# can't boot the recovery mode

Tags: boot, recovery-mode

I can't boot the recovery mode.

A system normal boot is OK. But I can't boot the recovery mode. 
After selecting it in grub menu it starts but stops in a progress on a line:

> **[drm] Initialized radeon 2.39.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0**

How to fix it?

-
Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS Open-source graphics